# Algorithm to recompile only necessary files with makefile given dependent source file should also recompile

Tags: algorithm

`make` tool in `UNIX` only recompile those files that were changed after the most recent compilation, and any intermediate files in the compilation that
depend on those that were changed.

A `[Makefile]` is typically composed of
a list of source files that must be compiled.

`

```
Each of these source files is dependent on some of the other files which are listed. 
Thus a source file
must be recompiled if a file on which it depends is changed. 

    Assuming
    you have a list of which files have been recently changed, as well as a list
    for each source file of the files on which it depends
```

,

How to design an algorithm
to recompile only those necessary source file.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) which essentially is a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). You need to create the graph that reflects the dependencies between the files and then run the topological sorting algorithm on that graph. If a file changes you need to recompile all the files that are before that file in the topological order.